# tpm2.RSADecrypt error inconsistent attributes golang

Tags: go

I use tpm2 to encrypt and decrypt data with RSA. Encrypt function work well but cannot decrypt.

First, I create RSA Key and persistence it:

```
var (
    publicKeyTemplate = tpm2.Public{
        Type:       tpm2.AlgRSA,
        NameAlg:    tpm2.AlgSHA256,
        Attributes: tpm2.FlagFixedTPM | tpm2.FlagFixedParent | tpm2.FlagSensitiveDataOrigin | tpm2.FlagUserWithAuth | tpm2.FlagRestricted | tpm2.FlagDecrypt | tpm2.FlagNoDA,
        AuthPolicy: nil,
        RSAParameters: &tpm2.RSAParams{
            Symmetric: &tpm2.SymScheme{
                Alg:     tpm2.AlgAES,
                KeyBits: 256,
                Mode:    tpm2.AlgCFB,
            },
            KeyBits: 2048,
        },
    }
)

func createRSAKey(rwc io.ReadWriteCloser, ownerPassword string, persistentHandler tpmutil.Handle) {
    srkHandle, publicKey, err := tpm2.CreatePrimary(
        rwc,
        tpm2.HandleOwner,
        tpm2.PCRSelection{},
        "",
        ownerPassword,
        publicKeyTemplate)

    log.Println(publicKey)

    err = tpm2.EvictControl(rwc, "", tpm2.HandleOwner, srkHandle, persistentHandler)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

Then I encrypt data with tpm2.RSAEncrypt, it works well

```
    rwc, err := tpm2.OpenTPM()

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    ownerPassword := "123456"
    persistentHandler := tpmutil.Handle(0x81000020)

    // createRSAKey(rwc, ownerPassword, persistentHandler)

    en, err := tpm2.RSAEncrypt(rwc, persistentHandler, []byte("abcdef"), &tpm2.AsymScheme{
        Alg:  tpm2.AlgOAEP,
        Hash: tpm2.AlgSHA256,
    }, "label")

    log.Printf("Encrypted: %x\n", en)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

But I cannot decrypt the encrypted data. It shows `error code 0x2 : inconsistent attributes`

```
    de, err := tpm2.RSADecrypt(rwc, persistentHandler, ownerPassword, en, &tpm2.AsymScheme{
        Alg:  tpm2.AlgOAEP,
        Hash: tpm2.AlgSHA256,
    }, "label")

    log.Printf("Decrypted: %x\n", string(de))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
```

What 's wrong in my code? Thanks very much!